# Optimizely not working on production app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, ios11, optimizely

There is some issue with editing mode on production app (downloaded from app store).
I've implemented all required setting. When I build app from Xcode to my device, then send link from website to myself, clicking this link opens app end enters editing mode. Same result when using TestFlight builds.
But if the app is downloaded from AppStore, clicking the link opens app well, but it is no way to enter editing mode! Help please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Optimizely Mobile Classic, edit mode is disabled on apps downloaded from the app store. We don't want all of your customers being able to enter edit mode by using the gesture or the link.

Comment: Is the issue that I have Mobile Classic implmented not Optimizely X Mobile?

Comment: No. The issue is that in Optimizely Classic Mobile, we do not allow apps downloaded from google play or the app store to enter edit mode for security purposes.

Comment: But what about X version? Do you allow to enter edit mode in Optimizely X Mobile in downloaded apps?

Comment: There is no edit mode in Optimizely X Mobile since there is no visual editor in Optimizely X Mobile.